# flutter set state like instagram post

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

sorry my english I hope I can explain exactly what I want. If I create the imageCount variable in the else part, the set state does not happen. but if I create it globally it becomes set state but this time it changes on each image. This is my code, just like Instagram, posts are coming, they are listed one below the other. I'm also trying to print the image numbers, now how should I define this variable? Whichever post the user scrolls through, its number will increase by 1.

```
Widget _imageDisplay(int index) {

if (postsList == null) {
  return null;
} else {
int imageCount=1;  //this variable
  return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
    child: Stack(children: [
      PhotoViewGallery(
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            imageCount = index + 1;
          });

        },
        customSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
        backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        pageOptions: _photoPageOpt(index),
      ),
      Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: Text(imageCount.toString() +
              '/' +
              postsList[index].images.length.toString()))
    ]),
  );
}
```

}
[image: what i'm trying to do]

Answer (score 1):

The variable `imageCount` needs to be part of the state of your Stateful Widget, otherwise `setState` does not have an effect. So it needs to be declared in your class that extends `State<MyWidget>`.

When `_imageDisplay` is called, if `postsList` is null, you need to return a widget, you can return an empty container, like `SizedBox()`.

Now, in order to control the logic on when your variable `imageCount` is updated, you need to put the logic inside the `setState` function.

Unfortunately, I did not understand well what exactly you want to achieve but try to express that into a condition that will control the update of the image counter, like the following:

```
setState(() {
    if(condition) {
        imageCount = index + 1;
    }
});
```